# Attach additional IPs to VPS (debian) and use these static IPs for docker

Tags: linux-networking, docker

I created a VPS and added additional IPs as alias. So my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.x.x.91
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        post-up /sbin/ip route add 192.99.68.1 dev eth0
        post-up /sbin/ip route add default via 192.99.68.1
        pre-down /sbin/ip route del default via 192.99.68.1
        pre-down /sbin/ip route del 192.99.68.1 dev eth0
        dns-nameserver 213.186.33.99
        dns-search vps.ovh.ca


# below is the additional ip alias
auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 144.x.x.100
        netmask 255.255.255.255
```

The good thing is that a local http server responds on both IPs (yeah). As a second step I want to create docker containers and assign each container to another IP. I tried [Jessie's Tutorial](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/ips-for-all-the-things/), but I have no inet-connectivity inside my container (e.g., I cannot ping IP-addresses).

`docker network create --subnet=144.x.x.0/24 --gateway 144.x.x.254  staticUSA1
docker run --net staticUSA1 --ip 144.x.x.100 some_container`

Do I have to setup a gateway or something else for my alias?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to your problem, NaN?